# Macbook Pro doesn't accept any incoming connections - Firewall disabled!

Tags: network, wifi, ssh, remote-desktop, firewall

My MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 doesn't respond to Ping, SSH, and Remote Access.

What I tried so far:

- Made sure "stealth mode" was disabled on Firewall
- Disabled the Firewall entierly
- Resetted all network configurations (removing plist files on `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`)
- Removed the Wi-Fi adapter and re-added it
- Removed any VPN apps (wireguard)
- Updated to the latest macOS version

It can access all devices on my local network, but no devices can access it.
I have no idea what else I can try.

Here's my files under `/Library/LaunchDeamons/`, if it helps:

```
com.adobe.ARMDC.Communicator.plist
com.adobe.ARMDC.SMJobBlessHelper.plist
com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist
com.adobe.agsservice.plist
com.aescripts.ZXP-Installer.helper.plist
com.ambrosiasw.ambrosiaaudiosupporthelper.daemon.plist
com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskAdminHelper.plist
com.daisydiskapp.DaisyDiskStandAlone.AdminHelper.plist
com.diebold.warsaw.plist
com.docker.vmnetd.plist
com.ea.origin.ESHelper.plist
com.google.keystone.daemon.plist
com.hanynet.icefloor.plist
com.intel.haxm.plist
com.macpaw.CleanMyMac-setapp.Agent.plist
com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist
com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist
com.nomachine.server.plist
com.nomachine.uninstall.plist
com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist -> /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Resources/com.oracle.java.Helper-Tool.plist
com.paragon-software.extfs.loader.plist
com.paragon-software.extfsd.plist
com.paragon-software.installer.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfs.loader.plist
com.paragon-software.ntfsd.plist
com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.Helper.plist
com.stclairsoft.AppTamerAgent.plist
org.virtualbox.startup.plist -> ../Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/org.virtualbox.startup.plist
```

Comment: Try the following... Boot to **macOS Recovery** and in **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu ascertain your **IP** address using `ifconfig`. Then from another system on your **LAN** `ping` the **IP** address. You should immediately get back valid replies from `ping` because from **macOS Recovery** there should be nothing blocking it from a `ping`.  Let us know the result.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading Icefloor. Even having that listed implies you are still running a second firewall. Icefloor is a GUI to configure the OpenBSD packet filter firewall builtin to the macOS Mach kernel. Icefloor is older software that is no longer supported nor maintained by the developer. It’s recommended that you switch to the Murus Firewall app to replace Icefloor. Neither app is an actual firewall but just a GUI front end to configuring the builtin PF firewall on macOS. You can do all the configuration via a text editor and command line. It’s just not nearly as easy.

The PF firewall is in addition to the GUI firewall you already disabled. To disable the PF firewall you do so from the Terminal.

```
 sudo pfctl -d
```

If your computer is managed by an IT department you may find you cannot turn it off or if you can it will turn itself back on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue may be a simple one. Have you gone into **System Preferences/Sharing** and configure & enabled the **Remote Management, Remote Apple Events, Remote Login etc.** Services?